# Multi threading IMAP backup [python]

Tags: python, multithreading, imap

I have the following python script which works freat to save IMAP folder to local .eml files. I want to do backup of my old email, but it has pretty large inbox. Is there anyway the below code can be modified with multi threads? Or perhaps several loops, so that it works faster on large IMAP folders?

Thanks a mil!

```
import sys
import imaplib
import getpass

IMAP_SERVER = ''
EMAIL_ACCOUNT = ""
EMAIL_FOLDER = "Inbox"
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY = './'

PASSWORD = getpass.getpass()


def process_mailbox(M):
    """
    Dump all emails in the folder to files in output directory.
    """

    rv, data = M.search(None, "ALL")
    if rv != 'OK':
        print "No messages found!"
        return

    for num in data[0].split():
        rv, data = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        if rv != 'OK':
            print "ERROR getting message", num
            return
        print "Writing message ", num

        f = open('%s/%s.eml' %(OUTPUT_DIRECTORY, num), 'wb')
        f.write(data[0][1])
        f.close()

def main():
    M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(IMAP_SERVER)
    M.login(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, PASSWORD)
    rv, data = M.select(EMAIL_FOLDER)
    if rv == 'OK':
        print "Processing mailbox: ", EMAIL_FOLDER
        process_mailbox(M)
        M.close()
    else:
        print "ERROR: Unable to open mailbox ", rv
    M.logout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried fetching more than one message at a time?  Fetch is more than capable of fetching multiple messages: `m.fetch("1:*", (RFC822)")` will fetch ALL the messages in your mailbox, but that's a good way to run out of memory.

If you have lots of memory, maybe try fetching in batches of one hundred.  This will probably speed it up about 20 to 50 times, since the bottleneck is usually network roundtrips.

Comment: thanks for your tip
I tried doing the M.fetch("1:100", '(RFC822)') in the above code, just to see how it works for the first 100 files (and then would've corrected for the num-th message). However I am just getting 1st message in loop, each time. (as long as the loop works, for all messages in the IMAP folder)

Comment: Well yes, you will have to adjust the rest of your code.  Your loop will have to grab batches of 100, and data will return 200 array parts that you will have to iterate through to write them to the file.  Start with "1:3" and see the format of the data in your data variable.

Answer (score 0):

I use the thread pools for work loads like this and the number of workers can be adjusted very easy. Here is a template for you.

```
def my_imap_function(lid,hid):
    .....
    
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:

            batches[(0,99), (100,199) ... ]
            futures = [executor.submit(my_imap_function, lowid, highid) for lowid, highid in batches]
            for future in as_completed(futures):
                if future.result() is False:
                    print('this batch failed', future.result())
```

more on this is here https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html